# What does the name Nemuel mean?

Tags: hebrew

I looked at the Strong's Concordance and it says perhaps "Day of EL/God".  Any insight into what this name may mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation of 'Day of G-d' would be 'Yemuel' - 'ימואל' i.e. an amalgam of the hebrew word for day - יום and קל - G-d. This name is the alternative version of the name of Shimon's son (see [Bereishis 46:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.46.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

The name Nemuel - נמואל is referenced to the same individual in [Divrei Hayamim 1 4:24](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.4.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and would mean 'Circumcised of (or for) G-d'.

See [here](https://www.oztorah.com/2011/08/the-two-wise-women-of-proverbs-chapter-31/#.XwpH5xOSmUk) for further elaboration.